# Cloudinary image not resizing if url set via javascript

Tags: javascript, cloudinary

So I have the following code:

and in my html I have this:

```
<img data-src="asaadmahmood.com/introImage.png" class="cld-responsive" />
```

```
import { Cloudinary } from 'cloudinary-core';

/**
 * Cloudinary instance
 */
const cloudinary = new Cloudinary({
    cloud_name: '********',
    secure: true,
});

/**
  *
  * @function
  * @param {string} img cloudinary image ID
  * @return {string} The generated image url
  */
 const createImageUrl = img => {
    return cloudinary.url(img, {
        responsive: true,
        width: 'auto',
        client_hints: 'true',
        fetchFormat: 'auto',
        quality: 'auto',
        crop: 'scale',
    });
};

const images = document.querySelectorAll('img[data-src]');
[...images].forEach((image) => {
    const dataSrc = image.getAttribute('data-src');
    image.src = createImageUrl(dataSrc);
})
```

Now even though I have resized my browser to around 200px width, and the image size is around 200px, the instrinsic size is still around 1000px (the original image size).

What can I do to make it responsive with the javascript code?

**Important note:**
If I supply the url like this:

```
<img 
    data-src="https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_auto,c_scale/smiling_man.jpg" 
    class="cld-responsive">
```

And do this:

```
cloudinary.responsive();
```

The images start working fine and are resized accordingly.
But the images don't work without:
`cloudinary.responsive();`

And `cloudinary.responsive();` messes up my url when I generate my url via javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code below, there is a separate data attribute for public id. Also, there is a listener to make sure all DOM elements are rendered. You still need to call `.responsive()` to get a responsive image and you will see your URL modified as Cloudinary substitutes different widths for different sized view ports. The responsive function looks for a URL, not a public id, in data-src and then replaces the w_auto in the URL with widths based on viewport.
https://responsive.rpeltz.repl.co/index2.html

```
<body>
    <img data-publicid="sample" data-src="" class="cld-responsive" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        /**
         * Cloudinary instance
         */

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
            const cld = cloudinary.Cloudinary.new({
                cloud_name: 'demo',
                secure: true,
            });

            /**
             *
             * @function
             * @param {string} img cloudinary image ID
             * @return {string} The generated image url
             */
            const createImageUrl = img => {
                return cld.url(img, {
                    responsive: true,
                    width: 'auto',
                    client_hints: 'true',
                    fetchFormat: 'auto',
                    quality: 'auto',
                    crop: 'scale',
                });
            };

            const images = document.querySelectorAll('img[data-publicid]');
            [...images].forEach((image) => {
                const dataPublicId = image.getAttribute('data-publicid');
                const src = createImageUrl(dataPublicId);
                image.setAttribute('data-src', src);
                cld.responsive();
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code in this sandbox:
https://replit.com/@rpeltz/Responsive#index.html

The way to see the responsiveness is to open devtools, go to network tab, clear and refresh page.  Click on the reponsive button and make the image really small.  Then enlarge the image.  You'll see that the size of the image grows as you enlarge the device/window size.  Then red cancels in the network tab are because I'm dragging the window and it doesn't need to create new sizes if you're dragging quickly.[image]

Comment: I already mentioned that it works fine if I don't generate the url with javascript. I want the responsive view to work even if I'm generating the whole url like in my example above with javascript.